# specifying column names of a data frame within a function ahead of time

Tags: r

Suppose you're trying to create a data frame within a function.  I would like to be able to define the column names ahead of time as one of the parameters of the function.  Take the following code:

```
  foo <- function(a) {
    answer <- data.frame(a=1:5)
    return(answer)
    }
```

In the above example, I would like to be able to specify the value of the column name in the function `foo()`, e.g. `foo('my.name')` so that answer has the column name `my.name` instead of `a`.  I imagine you could code this up within the function using `colnames()`, but I was interested in an alternative approach.

Comment: I can't think of anything simpler than using `colnames(answer) <- a` at the end of foo. If you had the names as names in a list, you could use `as.data.frame(list(a=1,b=2,c=3))`. Can you clarify why colnames seems clunky to you in your particular case?

Comment: Well suppose the data frame had multiple columns.  In that case, you would need to write something more involved like `colnames(answer)[colnames(answer)=='a'] <- 'foo' `  I was mainly interested in an alternative to explicitly writing it out that perhaps would involve something related to `substitute()`.

Comment: It might be more useful if you gave a concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish, and perhaps describe a bit on your idea of using substitute()

Comment: If colnames seems clunky, how about using structure?  structure(data.frame(1:5), names=c("mycolumnname"))

Answer (score 7):

Using `colnames` is the only way that I'm aware of for a data.frame, although colnames() is itself a vector so there's no need to do any iterating on it.  This version handles two columns:

```
foo <- function(cname) {
   answer <- data.frame(1:5, 1:5)
   colnames(answer) <- cname
   return(answer)
}
> foo(c("a","b"))
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative using `substitute` and `eval`.

```
foo <- function(var) {
  eval(substitute(data.frame(var = 1:5)), list(var = as.name(var)))
}
```

I hope you'll agree that the `colnames` solution is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

A minor adjustment to Shane's code, in case you really want to use `substitute`, or you really can't be bothered to type the extra quotes.

```
foo <- function(a) {
   answer <- data.frame(1:5)
   colnames(answer) <- as.character(substitute(a))
   answer
}
foo(mycolname)

  mycolname
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
5         5
```

Answer (score 1):

The setNames function will suffice:

```
> foo <- function(a,nm) {
+     answer <- data.frame(a=1:5)
+     setNames(answer, nm)
+     }
> foo(1:10, 'bar')
  bar
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```